# Transfer a WordPress domain

Tags: wordpress

I recently wanted to transfer a wordpress.com blog on my own server.

The domain was purchased from wordpress.com, so WordPress is the owner of domain.

The domain was expired few weeks ago, and I didn't renew it from wordpress.com because I want to be the owner and purchase it from a registrar. Actually, the whois say that this domain will expire in 1 year, so WordPress has renewed it, in order to force me to purchase it on wordpress.com.

But since few days, even if I want to renew my domain on wordpress.com, WordPress say this domaine is already taken and I can't use it. But WordPress is still the owner of domain, and no one took it.

I don't get any answer from the WordPress support. So I don't know what I do for get my domain. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to renew the domain through wordpress.com and then follow these domain transfer steps to move the domain do another registrar.

https://en.support.wordpress.com/transfer-domain-registration/

Comment: Thanks,
But my domain is not in the list, and when I want to add it with "add domain" button, wordpress said "this domain is taken". So I can't get it

Comment: This might be because you let your domain expire. There is a chance that WordPress.com still has it registered to themselves or that someone else swooped in and took it. If WordPress wants you to renew it from them you will have to do that before you can transfer it.

Comment: Thanks,
So I'm going to try to renew my wordpress account and after try to renew my domain on wordpress.com